# React Hook Form checkbox group is submitting as false when nothing is selected

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

I have a component that is a checkbox group:

```
const CheckboxGroup = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.options.map(option => (
                <input 
                    id={option.id}
                    type="checkbox"
                    value={option.value}
                    {...register("my-checkbox")}
                />
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

With an accompanying Yup validation schema:

```
{
    'my-checkbox': yup.array().notRequired()
}
```

The overall form looks like this:

```
import { useForm, FormProvider } from "react-hook-form"

const MyForm = () => {
   const formMethods = useForm()
   const { handleSubmit } = formMethods

   const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data)

    return (
        <FormProvider>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                <CheckboxGroup />
            </form>
        </FormProvider>
    )
}
```

However, I noticed that when submitting with no options selected (without selecting anything at all), the resulting submit data is `false`, instead of an empty array. (The `console.log` in the code above is what I'm referring to)

```
{ 'my-checkbox': false }
```

If I select an option, it is this:

```
{ 'my-checkbox': ['Option selected'] }
```

If I select an option and then unselect it, it is this:

```
{ 'my-checkbox': [] }
```

Because of the occurrence of this `false` value, my validation is not working upon initial submit when selecting nothing at all. How do I get the submit of the checkbox group to always be an empty array if nothing is selected?

Alternatively, how do I modify my validation schema to account for the possibility of a `false` value?

Comment: We need more code. Especially the code responsible for sending the data.

Comment: Unfortunately, you have to manage it manually, by `JSON.parse(value)` to turn `"false"` into `false`.
As for the empty string when you have all false, you need to manage this one manually too.

Answer (score 0):

Little bit late here but recently got into your situation, with a different scenario but the main idea is the same: if you send the form data without checking an input from a checkbox group/array you will get false as response.

It takes me some time to figure out this problem, tried few things, dive into react-hook-form docs and as a simple solution is to set empty array value to the checkbox group. Based on your example:

```
const { handleSubmit, setValue } = formMethods

useEffect(() => {
    setValue("my-checkbox", [])
}, [])
```

In this way you can manage yup.array() as you desire.